# DataSet hasChanges() always returns false

Tags: c#, dataset

```
DataSet exportData = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getOutput);
da.Fill(exportData);
exportData.HasChanges()
```

`ExportData.hasChanges()`
 always returns false. Why? It should return true since it has a lot of new records inserted.

Comment: Because you just filled it from the data source.

Comment: But exportData has just been filled from a database, and (unless you've omitted some code in your question) there are no changes to the underlying data. If it returned true then you'd have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because the last what `DataAdapter.Fill` will do is to call `AcceptChanges`. You can change this behaviour with the [`AcceptChangesDuringFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.acceptchangesduringfill.aspx) property(default `true`).

In general the `RowState` is used to determine what to do with this record. If you add a new record to a DataTable, it's [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) will change to `Added`. Now a DataAdapter would know what to do when he should update this table.

But because actually you haven't added new records it would double all records if the default wouldn't be `AcceptChangesDuringFill`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `AcceptChangesDuringFill`

```
 DataSet exportData = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getOutput);
 da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
 da.Fill(exportData);
 exportData.HasChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks. AcceptChangesDuringFill was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the meaning of `HasChanges`. When you ask for `HasChanges`, you

> Get a value indicating whether the DataSet has [your] changes, including new, deleted, or modified rows.

When you read from the DB, your data set is unchanged from the DB's perspective: it has exactly what's in the database, i.e. it is "clean". When you add, change, or remove data in the data set, the data set gets "dirty", so `HasChanges` starts returning `true`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
What is than the best way to test if there are some records in ds?
if(exportData.Tables[0].Rows.Count){}
Count is not the best way I guess.

Comment: I don't think `exportData.Tables[0].Rows.Count` is a valid solution, because the first table may not have records. You may want to post this as a separate question. You should also accept one of the answers here to let others know that you are no longer looking for an improved solution to the `HasChanges` question.

Answer (score 0):

This value becomes true if you made changes to dataset and have not called `"DataSet.AcceptChanges"`. In the meantime you can call `RejectChanges` to roll back to last time `AcceptChanges` were called.